# Mirror a group of cells elsewhere in the same sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, mirroring, visual-basic

I am trying to have an interactive table multiple places in my sheet to prevent my users from having to scroll repetitively through this massive sheet. every time this table is updated from any of the locations, I'd like all the tables to update. I have a (possibly useless) start:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("M205:p205")
    Set r2 = Range("m207:p207")
    If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r2.Value = r1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
        r1.Value = r2.Value
End Sub
```

but this only "mirrors" cells one direction. I have no clue how to make it two-way. Ideally, I'd have 4 of these interactive tables all updating one another.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code is actually a very good start!

I've improved it a bit to work for your scenario:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 as Range, r4 as Range
    Dim TempRng as Range
    Set r1 = Range("M205:p205")
    Set r2 = Range("m207:p207")
    set r3 = Range(<your_address3>)
    set r4 = Range(<your_address4>)
    If not Intersect(Target, r1) is Nothing then
        set TempRng = r1
    Else If not Intersect(Target, r2) is Nothing then
        set TempRng = r2
    Else If not Intersect(Target, r3) is Nothing then
        set TempRng = r3
    Else If not Intersect(Target, r4) is Nothing then
        set TempRng = r4
    Else 
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.Enableevents = False
    r1.Value = TempRng.Value 
    r2.Value = TempRng.Value 
    r3.Value = TempRng.Value 
    r4.Value = TempRng.Value 
    Application.Enableevents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow This looks great! This is kinda what I envisioned in my head, but I think when I tried the else loops I couldn't get it to work. thank you for your work!

... just like I can't this one to work either hahah! I hacked around a bit and still no dice. Any ideas? I'm on Microsoft office standard 2013 if it matters

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work? Do you get any error message? Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to mirror the cells in order for users to constantly see the same cells. Excel offers three native methods for managing the "view" of spreadsheet:

1. Split windows (View > Split). Splits one sheet into two horizontal or two vertical sections or four quadrants of the same sheet (depends if you select a row, a column or a single cell before clicking Split).
2. Freeze Panes (View > Freeze Panes). Similar to Split, but top/left/top-left sections are frozen in place and can't be scrolled.
3. New Window (View > New Window, followed by View > Arrange all). This option creates two open "worksheet views" of the same file. Very useful to view separate sheets of the same file simultaneously. Notice the ":1" and ":2" numbers next to the filename top-centre. This indicates which view window is currently active.

All these advanced view options will save with the file and will be restored if you save, close and reopen the file.

Hope it helps! If you need more info on any of these methods, just search e.g. "how to use  freeze panes in excel" in either google or youtube.